# Знак "Любознательный"

Tags: поддержка, знаки

> Задавайте интересные вопросы в течение 5 дней и поддерживайте
>   положительный баланс голосов

Мне кажется, описание затруднительно для понимания. Ибо понятие "интересный" вопрос крайне неконкретно. Исходя из оригинального описания на `SO.com`, я так понимаю, что для получения знака надо задать вопрос и принять ответ на него.

Кроме того, оригинальное описание баджа гласит:

> Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a
>   positive question record

Речь ведётся о пяти "отдельных" днях. То бишь, один вопрос надо задать в любой день, следующий вопрос в какой-то другой день. И таких действий должно быть 5. А это, имхо, плохо вяжется с фразой "в течение 5 дней", ибо наталкивает на мысль о пяти днях подряд и как-бы намекает, что надо поторопиться.

P.S. Я, собственно, сам это достижение не получил и совсем не понимаю, за что оно даётся, потому и решил поднять вопрос о грамотном толковании.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. 5 любых дней, не обязательно подряд. Но несколько вопросов в день - это один день. 
   Кстати, я сначала тоже думал, что подряд. Наверное, надо переформулировать...
2. Принимать ответ не требуется.
3. Положительный баланс голосов - это [вообще другое](/a/1533/178988).